# nl2br me arruina las urls

Tags: php, regex

Tengo un pequeño formulario con php donde se introduce texto.

El formulario permite añadir un embed de Youtube colocando youtube y seguido el id como por ej.

> youtubeRzCZxjzOHFo

Ahora, para que el ID del video se convierta en embed uso preg_replace y funciona bien.

El problema es que utilizo la función nl2br para los saltos de linea, y si por ej. en el formulario se hace lo siguiente:

> youtubeRzCZxjzOHFo
>
> otra secuencia de texto

cuando preg_replace reemplaza youtube por un embed, el embed se genera así:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RzCZxjzOHFo<br />"></iframe>
```

incluyendo en el iframe el `<br/>`

Si quito la función nl2br todo funciona correcto... O sea, el embed con preg_replace se genera y el video se ve bien, pero no funcionan los saltos de linea.

A la hora de procesar los posts, el preg_replace está ANTES del nl2br, no se si esto tendrá que ver (lo puse despues del nl2br y sigue igual...

¿Que opciones tengo para que al colocar el ID y que si hago el salto de linea no se corrompa?

Actualizo:

Este es mi preg_replace

```
$string = preg_replace('/youtube(.*)/', '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el `preg_replace`, deberías publicarlo para estar seguro. Pero si en el mismo NO estás incluyendo el salto de línea después del código de YouTube, el `nl2br` lo va a reemplazar siempre por un `<br>`.

Lo que tenés que hacer es incluirlo en el reemplazo:

```php
$string = preg_replace('/youtube(.*?)\s/', '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${1}"></iframe>', $string);
```

`\s` hace referencia a un espacio, es decir que el espacio que se encuentra después del código de YouTube también es reemplazado por el código del iframe.

Si con eso no funciona, se puede probar con `[\r\n|\n|\s]` en vez de `\s`. `\r\n` es un salto de línea en Windows y `\n` en UNIX.

Comment: Hola, @azeós Gracias pro tu ayuda.

No me funcionó añadiendo el modificador que mencionabas. Te dejo mi preg replace para que lo veas (lo añado a la pregunta).

Comment: @2147482530 Tu regex efectivamente NO remueve el salto de línea. Estoy probando con `/youtube(.*?)[\r\n|\n|\s]/` y funciona sin problemas. Proba hacer un echo antes del `nl2br` para ver como está quedando el `ifirame`.

Comment: algo deberé estar haciendo mal, @azeós, ya que añadiendo los modificadores que mencionas, el iframe sigue quedando del siguiente modo:

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/H-KlLOjfxWg<br />
"></iframe>ttr</p>`

Como verás, incluye el salto de linea dentro de la url...

Comment: @2147482530 Eso te aparece si haces un echo antes del `nl2br`?

Comment: si, @azeós. Me aparece eso. Aunque lo arreglé poniendo:

`$string = preg_replace('/<br(.*)>/', "\n", $string);

$string = preg_replace('/youtube(.*)/', '<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1"></iframe>', $string);

$string = preg_replace('/\n/', "<br>", $string);`

Aunque ahora cuando hago un espacio en blanco me incluye en el embed el espacio en blanco...

Comment: @2147482530 si te aparece eso, el `<br>` viene de antes. Estás levantando de la DB el string o viene directo de un formulario? Fijate si en el medio no lo estás modificando de alguna manera. En el primer `preg_replace` reemplazá el ´<br>´ por `''` (un string vacío) y listo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tus líneas deben estar termiando en formato Windows: `\r\n`

Al utilizar `.*` el punto puede consumir cualquier caracter excepto `\n`. Así pues, estás consumiendo (y guardando en el grupo de captura) `\r`, que luego es reemplazado por `<br>` por la función `nl2br`

Prueba a utilizar `\S` para consumir caracteres (significa cualquier caracter excepto `blancos` (saltos de línea, blanco, tabulador...)

Por ejemplo:

```
youtube(\S*)
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/VMQeFt):